# Embed different rows with different formulas basis another column value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to embed the formulas into excel using Macro. My sample dataset looks like:

| Product | Type | Month_202008 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | Supply | 15 |
| xxx | Demand | 8 |
| xxx | Available | 7 |
| xxx | Fulfilled | 8 |
| yyy | Supply | 9 |
| yyy | Demand | 15 |
| yyy | Available | -6 |
| yyy | Fulfilled | 9 |

I want to assign formulas to column "Month_202008" basis value of column Type e.g. for product xxx, there should be no formula for Type == Supply OR Demand, however formula for Available = Supply - Demand (i.e. C2-C3) and for Fullfilled, formula used is =IF(C4>=0,C3,MIN(C2,C3)) (i.e. if available is positive then Fullfilled = Demand, else its minimum of Supply or Demand and then same logic for next product and so on

I can't figure out how to provide different formulas to different rows and how to repeat that after few rows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So Supply and Demand are hand entered values? But other labels should be formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked for me:

```
Sub add_formulas()
Dim x As Long
Dim strRng As String
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 4 To LR
    y = x + 1
    strRng = "C" & x
    strRng1 = "C" & y
    Range(strRng).Formula = "=C" & x - 2 & "-" & "C" & x - 2 & ""
    Range(strRng1).Formula = "=IF(C" & x & ">=0,C" & x - 1 & ",min(C" & x - 2 & ",C" & x - 1 & "))" & ""
    x = x + 3
Next x
End Sub
```